# phpldapadmin with STARTTLS

Tags: ldap, tls

I'm trying to configure OpenLDAP on Ubuntu using the the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html). I have enabled Start TLS with a certificate generated using my own CA certificate (since it is for internal use). I enforced Start TLS on the database using `olcSecurity` (set to `tls=1`). LDAP clients in general have no problem connecting it the server once I set the `TLS_CACERT` to the path of my CA certificate in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`, except for phpLDAPadmin.
I have enabled TLS in phpLDAPadmin confiuguration (`/etc/phpldapadmin/config.php`):

```
$servers->setValue('server','tls',true);
```

phpLDAPadmin throws a bunch of errors (culled from the post-login page, posted at the end). Does anyone know how to get phpLDAPadmin to play nice with Start TLS, or allow an exception to it?

Errors:

```
Array
(
    [class] => N/A
    [function] => debug_dump
    [file] => /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/functions.php
    [line] => 700
    [debug] => Array
        (
            [Incoming MSG] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Could not start TLS. (My LDAP Server)
                    [body] => Error: Could not start TLS. Please check your LDAP server configuration.
                    [type] => error
                )

            [existing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Could not start TLS. (My LDAP Server)
                            [body] => Error: Could not start TLS. Please check your LDAP server configuration.
                            [type] => error
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Authenticate to server
                            [body] => Successfully logged into server.
                            [type] => info
                        )

                )

        )
)

PHP Debug Backtrace
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/functions.php (444)
    Function    error (a:5:{i:0;s:22:"Redirect Loop Detected";i:1;s:4:"no...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/functions.php (701)
    Function    debug_dump_backtrace (a:2:{i:0;s:22:"Redirect Loop Detected";i:1;b:1;})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/ds_ldap.php (560)
    Function    system_message (a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:37:"Could not start TL...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/ds_ldap.php (186)
    Function    startTLS (a:1:{i:0;i:0;})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/ds_ldap.php (354)
    Function    connect (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"user";i:1;b:0;})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/ds_ldap.php (2104)
    Function    query (a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"base";s:26:"dc=cse,dc=iitb,dc=a...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/ds_ldap.php (2028)
    Function    getDNAttrValues (a:3:{i:0;s:26:"dc=cse,dc=iitb,dc=ac,dc=in";i:1;N;i...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Tree.php (186)
    Function    getDNAttrValue (a:2:{i:0;s:26:"dc=cse,dc=iitb,dc=ac,dc=in";i:1;s:1...)
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Tree.php (62)
    Function    addEntry (a:1:{i:0;s:26:"dc=cse,dc=iitb,dc=ac,dc=in";})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/page.php (227)
    Function    getInstance (a:1:{i:0;i:1;})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/page.php (418)
    Function    tree (a:0:{})
File    /usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/cmd.php (78)
    Function    display (a:0:{})
```

This was originally posted on Ask Ubuntu, but didn't receive any answers, and I figure that this problem is not about Ubuntu *per se*, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that this was a case of PEBKAC. The TLS certificate had the hostname of the server, whereas I was setting `localhost` in phpLDAPadmin. The hostname mismatch was causing the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Muru's answer above lead me to what worked. I changed this line in /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php from ...

```
$servers->setValue('server','host','ldap://127.0.0.1');
```

... to ...

```
$servers->setValue('server','host','ldap://login.example.com');
```

After restarting apache2 those errors went away.

In my case this was Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` on the server and add

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

This workaround is posted here [How do I solve `ldap_start_tls`() “Unable to start TLS: Connect error” in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689629/how-do-i-solve-ldap-start-tls-unable-to-start-tls-connect-error-in-php).

Comment: This will allow non TLS connection: : http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Server:server:tls